# Calling servlet post from jsf in different war

Tags: jsf, servlets, post

I want to call a Servlet which exists in a different war from my war. When user clicks a button we need to call the post method of the servlet. To implement this I did see an existing example which is slightly different but works in that case.

I am using jsf, so in the jsp there is a h:form with another html form inside of it. Below is the code:

```
<h:form>     
<div id="gform" class="column span-20 append-1">

    <h:outputText value="Text." /><br/><br/>

  <h:commandLink id="addPaymentButton" styleClass="button" onclick='autorenew();return false;'> <span><h:outputText value="Payment Option"/></span> </h:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a id="noThanksButton" href="#"><span><h:outputText value="No Thanks"/></span></a><br/><br/><br/>


  <h:outputText style="color:grey" value="Some text" />
     <div> </div>

    </div>


    <form id="hiddenSubmit" method="post" action="https://localhost.myapp.com/myapp/LoginRouter" >  
        <input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl" value="/myapp/customers/addNewSavedCCInfo.faces"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="jump_message" value="IAmJumpingToCC"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="jump_url" value="/premiumServices/myPage.htm"/>
        <input id="hiddenSubmitButton" type="submit" name="submit" style="display: none" value='' />
    </form>

    </h:form>
<script language="javascript">

function autorenew(){
    window.alert('In js fnt');
    document.hiddenSubmit.getElementById('hiddenSubmitButton').click();
    window.alert('In js fnt COMPLETE');
    return false;
}
```

So when the button is clicked, javascript is executed which submits the form to the servlet. However I can see in firebug that the second form which I need to submit does not appear.  I am not sure how I can call the post method of a servlet class in a different war. Any ideas welcome, I am really stuck!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML specification it's forbidden to nest `<form>` elements. The (mis)behaviour is browser dependent. Some browsers will send **all** parameters, some browsers will send only the data of the parent form, other browsers will send nothing.

You want to have a single form here. You can perfectly replace the `<h:form>` by a plain vanilla HTML `<form>` with the desired `action` pointing to the servlet in question.